# Separate .conf files for apps deployed to httpd

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I am not familiar with deploying web-apps but I have a few python modules that do related work and are to be deployed to one instance of httpd 2.4. I can deploy one using a .conf file in etc/httpd.conf.d. My first gut feeling was that I should be able to write separate .conf files for each app. But that is not working and can't find much documentation around this topic. Is it at all possible or must I define all virtual hosts in one .conf file?

Comment: Everything pertaining to one ``VirtualHost`` has to be in a single ``VirtualHost`` definition. You can't have multiple ``VirtualHost`` for same ``ServerName`` and port, they will not be merged. Are your applications for different ``VirtualHost``, or the same? Show an example.

Comment: Thanks. In my example, I have a service that queues requests to a queue, which are serviced by other services. In addition there is another service that receives database queries and services them. There is yet another service that receives and logs events. Given the above, I thought I should be able to write three .conf files for each of the services. Given that I want three separate .conf files, I'd think I'd end up with three different virtual hosts, right? However, I definitely do not want IP-based; is it an option in the way I am thinking about the problem.

Comment: If they need to all be available under the same host name, they must be defined in the same ``VirtualHost``.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will accept that as an answer.